# sed | grep weird behaviour in script

Tags: bash, sed

#### THE ISSUE

I have two files,

File1

> INT1;INT2;INT3
> INT4;INT5;INT6
> INT7;INT7;INT9

File2

> INT1;INT2;INT3

Next I'll grep the difference between the files and only take the integers of third column.

```
  DIFFERENCE=`grep -vxFf File1 File2 | awk 'BEGIN { FS = ";" } ; { print $3 }'`
```

resulting in

> INT6 INT9

Next I want to substitute the spaces with line breaks

```
echo $DIFFERENCE | sed 's/ /;\n/g'
```

which results in

> INT6;
>
> INT9

Just as it should.

Instead, when I do it in the script, it returns

> INT6
>
> INT9

Why does it do this in script, and is there solution to this / how can I modify my result easily?

#### ORIGINAL CODE - FOR CLARIFICATION

Original code and output here

```
     CODE=`grep -vxFf $FOUND $COMPARETO | awk 'BEGIN { FS = ";" } ; { print $3 }'` 
     echo "$CODE;" | sed 's/ /;\n/g' > "testfile"
```

> 8000070118157
> 8002820000804
> 3394700015011;

Comment: join the 90's and start using the `$(cmd)` form of cmd-substitution ;-) (instead of backtics). Also given your sample codes, there's no reason that you need the last line. All of that can be done with `awk` manipulations. Good luck.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intermediate output is not `INT6 INT9` on single line but already two lines, therefore `sed` doesn't replace anything.

You can do all of this in `awk` itself, for example

```
$ awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a){print $3 FS}' file2 file1
INT6;
INT9;
```

if you don't want the last `;`, perhaps easier to pipe to `sed '$ s/;$//'`

Comment: I completely forgot I don't have access to my script on the weekend.. I'll try your answer on monday, but when I echoed the intermediate output it was on a single line, but I'll take your word for it! I'll update asap if it works for me, thanks =)

Comment: echo suppresses line breaks, you need to use option `-e`